# running one command, n time at the same time with different parameter like parallel for using bash script

Tags: c++, linux, performance, bash, openmp

I want to run a command with different parameter AT THE SAME TIME , N time like a for loop in which all loops run at the same time

I know by using & at the end of specific line like this we can run them same time but I want a way that run that N time that can be variant

```
./a &
./a &
./a &
```

and can I run each one on specific core ? or should I something openMP and C to do like that ? if yes, how can I run commands with C++?

```
#paragma omp parallel
for(int i=0;i<n ; i++ )
{
///  ??? how can I run these command by c++
}
```

but even if it works, this solution work only if (n< #core) :(

Comment: Try using [GNU Parallel](http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/)

Comment: yes I know that but  is there alternative ?

Comment: You can use a loop with a counter, and when the counter gets to N you run `wait` to wait for all the background jobs to finish.

Comment: I up-voted you, simple solution :D thanks , I am feeling stupid

Comment: NO , I have used for before but they run sequential , you mean using for with one command end with & am I right ?

Comment: Yes, you can use `&` at the end of the line inside the `for`, and it will run that command in the background and continue the loop.

Comment: You can prepare N forks of a process then let those forks wait for a specific time with a time event about 500m to 2 seconds after or anything that's just enough for subprocesses to prepare before finally exec-ing the real command. You would have to calculate the target timeframe before creating the forks and let those forks wait for it.

Answer (score 0):

May be you can use std::thread...

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <string>

void runcmd(std::string param)
{
  // something like system(param.c_str());
}

int main() 
{
  std::thread* threadarray[10];
  for (int i=0; i<10; ++i)
      threadarray[i] = new std::thread(runcmd,"./a"); 

  for (int i=0; i<10; ++i) {
      threadarray[i]->join;
      delete threadarray[i];
  }

  return 0;
}
```

I think you can specify core id with sched_setaffinity.

look:
http://www.thinkingparallel.com/2006/08/18/more-information-on-pthread_setaffinity_np-and-sched_setaffinity/

Comment: Using `system(3)` to launch processes in a multithreaded application does not deliver portable results. On OS X `system(3)` is synchronised, which means that only one child processes would get launched at a time. The portable solution would be to use a proper combination of `fork(2)` and `exec(3)` in a loop and then implement a wait.

Answer (score 0):

```
N=3
eval params=({1..$N})
for param in ${params[*]}; do ./a $param& done
```